# Docker exec fails, permission denied: unknown

Tags: symfony, docker

I'm new to docker and I'm just trying to create a simple Symfony API. I ran docker-compose up -d which created these containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                         NAMES
071de3320346        willdurand/elk      "/usr/bin/supervisor…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:81->80/tcp                            simple-api_elk_1
c24132f645be        simple-api_nginx    "nginx"                  About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp                   simple-api_nginx_1
37128a03b667        simple-api_php      "php-fpm7 -F"            About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                        simple-api_php_1
aa7738c59891        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3307/tcp   simple-api_db_1
```

I then took the id from the simple-api_php and ran

`docker exec 37128a03b667 composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton symfony-api`

It returns:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: open /tmp/runc-process126262263: permission denied: unknown
```

here is my docker-compose.travis.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony
        MYSQL_USER: symfony
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
    php:
        build: ./php-fpm
        expose:
            - "9000"
        volumes:
            - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
            - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/var/logs
        links:
            - db
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
            - php
        volumes_from:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
    elk:
        image: willdurand/elk
        ports:
            - "81:80"
        volumes:
            - ./elk/logstash:/etc/logstash
            - ./elk/logstash/patterns:/opt/logstash/patterns
        volumes_from:
            - php
            - nginx
```

Just don't have enough knowledge to troubleshoot this.

Thanks!!

Comment: There are a lot examples (Symfony specific too) here for you: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/docker

Comment: I second @BentCoder's suggestion. But, generally speaking, in case of an error, why not exec into `bash` and run your command? You will get a complete output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should edit your elk service.

   ```
   elk:
     image: willdurand/elk
     ports:
       - "81:80"
     volumes:
       - ./elk/logstash:/etc/logstash
       - ./elk/logstash/patterns:/opt/logstash/patterns <-------- remove this line
     volumes_from:
       - php
       - nginx <-------- remove this line
   ```

Note: comments are marked with arrow <------

2. Also, if you still have the same issue - try to remove images and containers and then rebuild them.

   ```
   // This command will remove all containers and images in your docker-compose.travis.yml file
   $: docker-compose down

   // Or you can remove container and images manually
   $: docker rm container_name
   $: docker rmi image_name
   ```